# Initiate global bloc on Logout

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm providing bloc at top of all view to access at globally. When I'm doing logout and re-login without closing app, event not called because it is already initiate. Here, I want to refresh bloc on logout, so that **FetchList** and **UpdateCount** events got called when user logged In without closing app. How I can achieve this?

```
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => AppBloc()..add(const UpdateFcmToken())),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => getIt<ListBloc>()
            ..add(const FetchList())
            ..add(const UpdateCount()),
        ),
      ],
      child: const AppView(),
    );
  }
}
```

## For workaround, I add those event at login as well, but it will cause multiple request for fresh login.

Comment: Probably, after logging in, you go to the specific page in your app - call your BLoC functions from there and not during the bloc's initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

What about linking the bloc method:

```
 ..add(const FetchList())
 ..add(const UpdateCount()),
```

with the authentication stream that you're using in your app, I mean instead of calling the methods manually when creating the bloc, what about doing only this:

```
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => AppBloc()..add(const UpdateFcmToken())),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => getIt<ListBloc>(),
           ),
      ],
      child: const AppView(),
    );
  }
}
```

I assumethat you're using Firebase for authentication, and so, you can do something like this:

```
   FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
     if(user != null) {
        final yourBloc = // here you get the cubit either by direct access with   getIt<ListBloc>() of with context.read<ListBloc>(), based on your case.
     
      yourBloc
       ..add(const FetchList())
       ..add(const UpdateCount()),     } 
    }
```

and so now, you won't need to worry about doing it manually, since every time  a new user with authenticate (`user != null`), the events will be emited.